# Database results in a listView is not working

Tags: android, database

i m trying to get data from my database and present them to a listView.i m using two classes for my database:
1st class is the DBAdapter and the method i use to get data is:

```
   public String[] getData()
{
//  String[] columns =new String[]{DBHelper.ROWID, DBHelper.TITLE ,  DBHelper.AUTHOR, DBHelper.ISBN };

    String[] columns =new String[]{DBHelper.TITLE ,  DBHelper.AUTHOR, DBHelper.ISBN };
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result="";
    String sa = null;
    String sb = null;
    String sc = null;


    //int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ROWID);
    int is1=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TITLE);
        int is2=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.AUTHOR);
            int is3=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ISBN);

            for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
                //result=result+c.getString(is1)+" "+c.getString(is2)+" "+c.getString(is3)+"\n";
                 sa=c.getString(is1);
                 sb=c.getString(is2);
                 sc=c.getString(is3);
            }
              //Toast.makeText(HotOrNot.this, sa, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return new String[] {sa,sb,sc};
}
```

2.The secind class in SQLView and thats the way i m trying to create my list

```
public class SQLView extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */    

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.list_layout); 

       HotOrNot entry2=new HotOrNot(this);
       entry2.open();  
          String[] data2=entry2.getData();
          entry2.close();
          Toast.makeText(SQLView.this, data2[1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

       map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map.put("name",data2[0].toString());
       map.put("address", data2[1].toString());
       map.put("address2", data2[2].toString());

       mylist.add(map);






       // ...
       ListAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
                   data2, new int[] {R.id.rtextView1,R.id.rtextView2,R.id.rtextView3});
       list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

What i have to do in order to work?This is my first try to use database in android!

Now i just get an empty background...

EDIT:
With my toast i m getting the last item in position 1 that i added to db

Could anybody help me with the return statement in my DBHelper please?

Comment: For starters, use `ListActivity` as your base instead of `Activity`.

Comment: ok,i changed it!Just for curiosity,is it wrong to use activity for a list?i mean,i could use an image above the list,so in that way i had to use activity only,am i right?

Comment: You can have image in `ListActivity` too. There is no restriction except you must have `ListView` in the view hierarchy. It will have some helper apis which you need to capture use cases like clicking on an item etc. It makes your life easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the fixed code. Try this out.

```
ListAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
   new String[] { "name", "address", "address2"},
   new int[] {R.id.rtextView1,R.id.rtextView2,R.id.rtextView3});
list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

Basically you have to specify the columns/key of the map that you added. So it will map key from map to the corresponding view.

For looping issue, this will do the job:

```
for(int i=0; i<data2.length; i+=3) {
   HashMap<String, String> map;

   map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map.put("name",data2[i].toString());
   map.put("address", data2[i+1].toString());
   map.put("address2", data2[i+2].toString());

   mylist.add(map);
}
```

The `getData` fix:

```
ArrayList<String> arrForData = new ArrayList<String>();
//int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ROWID);
int is1=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TITLE);
    int is2=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.AUTHOR);
        int is3=c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ISBN);

        for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            //result=result+c.getString(is1)+" "+c.getString(is2)+" "+c.getString(is3)+"\n";
             arrForData.add(c.getString(is1));
             arrForData.add(c.getString(is2));
             arrForData.add(c.getString(is3));
        }
          //Toast.makeText(HotOrNot.this, sa, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return arrForData.toArray();
```

Comment: thanks havexz!!now the list is working but i only can see the last item i have added in my database!How can i solve it?

Comment: that is happening bcoz you are calling `mylist.add(map);` only once...which in this case corresponds to last item. You have to loop over your `data2` variable which contains all the data.

Comment: Could you please give me some help on it?may i use something like for?

Comment: i m really glad for your help but the loop job in not working in the way you suggested me..:(.I just get the final item

Comment: could my error be in the DBHelper class,and thats why i m only getting the last item?

Comment: well the other problem is in your `getData` method. There you are returning only last item `return new String[] {sa,sb,sc};` You have to fix it. The code mentioned in the answer is still needed. You have to add all items in the returned `String` array.

Comment: i only have to change the return statement or my for method in getData()?